# How does the OV pin protect against overvoltage?

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet, pins

This is the first time I've come across such pins on an IC. With a quick search, they are overvoltage supervisor pins hence to protect against overvoltage.

I was studying a power MUX [TPS212x](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2120.pdf?ts=1681058434189&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fpower-switches%252Fpower-muxes%252Fproducts.html). The power supply was connected to the OV pin with resistance in between (to bring voltage under operating conditions) as seen below:

[image]

For overvoltage protection, can't we just use a TVS diode whose breakdown is above the absolute max of the TPS212xIC?

How does the OV pin actually help against overvoltage if its listed absolute maximum is 6 V?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *How does the OV pin actually help against overvoltage if its listed
> absolute maximum is 6 V?*

It turns off the output preventing an input over-voltage damaging the load connected to the output. The absolute maximum value is irrelevant because the OV input trip threshold is 1 volt.

So, if the incoming supply is nominally 12 volts and, you wanted to protect the load on the output from getting more than (say) 13 volts, you would use a potential divider from the incoming supply to the relevant OV pin to produce 1 volt when the incoming supply is 13 volts. It's got nothing to do with the absolute maximum.

OV thresholds from [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2120.pdf?ts=1681058434189&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fpower-switches%252Fpower-muxes%252Fproducts.html): -

[image]

> *For overvoltage protection, can't we just use a TVS diode whose
> breakdown is above the absolute max of the TPS212xIC?*

The TVS diode would need to have a breakdown voltage that is significantly less than 24 volts and, in turn, you need to have a mechanism that protects the TVS diode from being ruptured if an overwhelming voltage surge was applied. Choosing the right TVS and the right protection for the TVS is tricky and needs lengthy consideration.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the explanation! Say if my IC was subject to transients so V(IN) max value of 24V is exceeded would the IC get destroyed?

What I mean to ask is the OV pin useful only when V(in) < max value i.e. 24V. 
Would I need surge protection apart from it say between the power supply & the IC?

Comment: (1) You cannot exceed 24 volts at either incoming supply. That's off bounds and the IC could easily be destroyed or impaired if you exceeded 24 volts. (2) for all other cases, the OV pins do what they do (as explained in my answer). (3) Surge protection will be needed if the incoming supplies could rise higher than 24 volts. You won't need surge protection on OV inputs.

Comment: Thank you! Understood it well.

Answer (score 0):

The over-voltage pin senses over-voltage condition through the resistive voltage divider, so 6V on it (the pin OV1) will happen when there is 24V on the IN1 pin, basically a 1:4 ratio set by the resistive divider. The resistor from OV1 pin to ground has 1/3 the resistance of the two resistors above it (from OV1 pin to IN1 pin) and vice versa; those 2 resistors above have 3 times the resistance of the resistor below the OV1 pin. If a lower overvoltage tripping point is desired, it can be set with these resistors, and a significantly lower voltage is normally used.

This IC is a power multiplexer which merely switches the supply voltage to the appropriate circuits "downstream" and protects them from damaging conditions. If it's supplying a 5V circuit which can't operate above 6V, you set the OV voltage to 6V or slightly below (like 5.8V).

Here is a quote from its datasheet:

> **9.3.5 Overvoltage Protection (OVx)** 
> Output Overvoltage Protection is available for both IN1 and IN2 in case either applied voltage is greater than the maximum supported load voltage. The VREF comparator on the OVx pins allow for the Overvoltage Protection threshold to be adjusted independently for each input. When overvoltage is engaged, the corresponding channel will turn off immediately. Fast switchover to the other input is supported if it is a valid voltage.

Comment: Does it just sense over-voltage, or does it do something to stop it from deteriorating the downstream circuitry as well?

Am I right in thinking that this would never happen as maximum V(in) is 24V, so anyhow there is no point in using power sources of voltage supply being greater than 24V.

Comment: @Harkirat I will add more to my answer in a few minutes to explain this. This circuit merely switches the supply voltage to the appropriate circuit "downstream" and protects it from damaging conditions. If it's supplying a 5V circuit which can't operate above 6V, you set the OV voltage to 6V or slightly below (like 5.8V).

Comment: Yep, I understood OV pin potential is set according to the load we're powering. 
I misunderstood and thought that the OV pin was for Power supply protection but it is for Load protection.

Comment: @Harkirat Exactly, that was confusing to me as well until I realized it's supposed to protect the load.

Comment: The control threshold is 1 volt and not 6 volt. 6 volts is the absolute maximum rating. 24 volts is the absolute maximum rating of incoming supply to the chip. Neither the 24 volts nor the 6 volts should be approached during normal operation.

Comment: @Andyaka You're right, I have mentioned something similar but failed to explain that part.